# Zweizeiliger Titel

Tags: style

Schreibe ich bei einem zweizeiligen Titel besser dies:

> Klassifizierung von Texten mit
>
> Methoden des Machine Learnings

**oder**

> Klassifizierung von Texten
>
> mit Methoden des Machine Learnings

Comment: Hach, klingt wie meine Thesis von vor gut 10 Jahren.... <retro>
Willkommen bei German SE!

Comment: *Machine-Learnings;* mit Bindestrich …

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Beides ist je nach Situation möglich:

- Die erste Variante ist vorzuziehen, wenn es sich bei *Klassifizierung von Texten mit ...* um eine Serie handelt, bei der *Methoden des Machine Learnings* (meines Wissens ist auf Deutsch übrigens auch *maschinelles Lernen* hier ein üblicher Begriff) eine Ausgabe darstellt und es weitere Ausgaben à la *Klassifizierung von Texten mit redaktionell aufbereiteten Tabellen*, *Klassifizierung von Texten mit Hilfe von Folksonomies* etc.
- Ist dies nicht der Fall, würde ich eher zur zweiten Variante tendieren.

Da der Zeilenumbruch relativ frei platzierbar zu sein scheint und es sich somit offenbar nicht um voll ausgefüllte Zeilen handelt, sondern um einen beliebig gelayouteten Text, haben allerdings layouttechnische Gesichtspunkte potenziell Priorität gegenüber obigen inhaltlichen Kriterien, beispielsweise:

- Muss der Text in ein rechteckiges Fenster passen?
- Muss der Text eine Grafik umfließen?
- Muss der Umriss des Textes ungefähr mit anderen Werken übereinstimmen?